# Schedule blocking operation each second in Vertx

Tags: multithreading, vert.x

I would like to schedule blocking operation which will run each second. My application is using Vertx and is written in Java.

What is the best way to run blocking code in Vertx each for example 1 second? I know that we have timers in Vertx, here is code sample of creating it:

```
long timerID = vertx.setPeriodic(1000, id -> {
System.out.println("And every second this is printed");
});
```

but what I want to achieve is to 1 main thread (Verticle1 thread) and 2 worker threads: Synchronizer thread and thread retrieving state (blocking operation) which will send this state to Synchronizer thread each 1 second.
In non-vertx code I will achieve this in simple way by using threads but in Vertx I have to use WorkerVerticle or vertx.setPeriodic method.

Important: I do not want to block main event loop.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your code in vertx.executeBlocking and write it in the usual blocking way